# Using ViewPager and GoogleMap V2 - How to enable page swiping to change page even when swiping on map(map scrolling is disabled)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-viewpager

So I have disabled scrolling on my map but at the same time, when I try to scroll left and right to swap the page in the ViewPager, the swipe is not recognized in the ViewPager as I think it still thinks that I am trying to scroll the map. How can I acomplish that?

```
public class VenueDetailsActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity{
     private static final String[] CONTENT = new String[] { "Camera", "Description", "Menu", "Contact", "Specials" };

 private Venue venue;
 private CameraFragment camera = null;
 private ContactFragment contact = null;
 private DescriptionFragment desc = null;
 private MenuFragment menu = null;
 private SpecialsFragment specials = null;
 private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.venue_details);
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize(){

        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        //get the Venue that was passed.
        venue = (Venue) b.getParcelable("venue");

        actionBar.setTitle(venue.getName());

        //create a fragment adapter object
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //find the viewpager in the view venue_details
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        //set the pager to keep total length of Content windows -1 screen fragments( this helps to not redraw the cameras every time you move thrugh tabs )
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(CONTENT.length-1);
        //set adapter for the pager.
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    /* This method handles the each click on the drawable menu */
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* Adapter CLASS to help with fragments */
    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            int var = position % CONTENT.length;
            switch(var){
                case 0:
                    //check to see if there is an instance already
                    if(camera == null){
                        camera = CameraFragment.newInstance(venue);
                    }
                    return camera; 
                case 1:
                    if(desc==null){
                        desc = DescriptionFragment.newInstance(venue);
                    }
                    return desc;
                case 2:
                    if(menu == null){
                        menu = MenuFragment.newInstance(venue);
                    }
                    return menu;
                case 3:
                    if(contact == null){
                        contact = ContactFragment.newInstance(venue);
                    }
                    return contact;
                case 4:
                    if(specials == null){
                        specials = SpecialsFragment.newInstance(venue);
                    }
                    return specials;    
            }
            return CameraFragment.newInstance(venue);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return CONTENT[position % CONTENT.length].toUpperCase();
        }

      @Override
        public int getCount() {
          return CONTENT.length;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the one fragment that I want to make sure that even swiping on the map will change my fragments.

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment{
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "ContactFragment:Content";
    private SupportMapFragment fragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LatLng venueLatLng ;

    private static Venue venue;

    public static ContactFragment newInstance(Venue venuePassed) {
        ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
        venue = venuePassed;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //create a LatLng object used to send coordinates to Google Maps
        venueLatLng = new LatLng(venue.getLocationCoordinates().getLatitude(), venue.getLocationCoordinates().getLongitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //get the child fragment manager
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        //find google maps's fragment that is inserted in the xml
        fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        if (fragment == null) {
            //create a new instance of the support fragment
            fragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
            fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (map == null) {
            map = fragment.getMap();
            Marker venueMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(venueLatLng)
                    .title(venue.getName())
                    .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                    .draggable(false));
            venueMarker.showInfoWindow();
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(venueLatLng, 15));
            map.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact, 
                container, false);
        TextView contact_text = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_text);
        contact_text.setText(venue.getAddress());
        TextView phone_number = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        phone_number.setText(venue.getPhoneNumber());
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);;
    }


}
```

Comment: How many "pages" do you have in the `ViewPager`?

Comment: i have 5 pages in the Viewpager

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anything inside the ViewPager to be clickable, try subclassing ViewPager.  Override dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e), and return false from it to prevent touch events from being claimed by the ViewPager's children.

Comment: well I do want stuff to be clickable but I am only referring to the swiping.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your problems comes from they way you are loading the `SupportMapFragment`. You should extend `SupportMapFragment` instead of `Fragment` and customize the `Map` like you do in `onResume()`.